# Unintended movement when animating a character in blender!

Tags: animation

So I have a LEGO minifigure model I have built.
I only want to animate a walk cycle.
I grab a leg and rotate it out.
Then I move down to another frame and now the head has turned as well!
 Has anybody else had this kind of experience and what can cause this?
TIA!
[image]

Comment: hard to tell, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: There you go! Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: you've created some keyframes but it looks like you haven't moved anything... anyway I think you should work on rigging because animating a character without armature is going to be hell

Comment: @moonboots ok thanks! I left Autodesk Maya behavior nd and I’m just learning my way around everything in Blender

Answer (score 1):

While playing with the scene I learned how to fix the unintended movement! Go to the outliner and delete the animation data there, then start setting new key frames and everything animates as intended, no extra parts are moving around!
Hope this is helpful to anybody else who encounters a similar situation.